# Send response but keep long running script going to prevent timeout?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, github-api, webhooks

I am wondering how to deal with this. I have a webhook endpoint which responds to a webhook call from Github.

It starts a long running process in where it clones the repository from which the webhook call was made.

```
/**
* The webhook endpoint.
*
* @param Request $request
* @return mixed
* @throws \Exception
*/
public function webhook(Request $request)
{
    // The type of GitHub event that we receive.
    $event = $request->header('X-GitHub-Event');

    $url = $this->createCloneUrl();
    $this->cloneGitRepo($url);

    return new Response('Webhook received succesfully', 200);
}
```

The problem with this is that Github gives an error when the response is not provided soon enough.

> We couldn’t deliver this payload: Service Timeout

This is rightfully so because my `cloneGitRepo` method is simply blocking the execution of the response and it is taking too long.

How can I still deliver a response to acknowledge to Github that the webhook call has been made successfully and start my long running process?

I am using Laravel for all of this with Redis, maybe something can be accomplished there? I am open to all suggestions.

Comment: You should use [Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues)

Comment: From docs __Queues allow you to defer the processing of a time consuming task, such as sending an email, until a later time. Deferring these time consuming tasks drastically speeds up web requests to your application.__

Comment: Or, you could use [Running Processes Asynchronously](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#running-processes-asynchronously), as the `Symfony\Component\Process\Process` is already included by laravel...

Comment: **Running Processes Asynchronously** should be easier to implement, queue needs some setup...

Comment: @ljubadr The queue is the correct way to go. The "asynchronous process" provided by Symfony does not survive its parent. So, when the response is returned, the child process will be killed before it completes its work.

Comment: Thanks I will look into queues. I haven't used them before, but I already have Redis set up since I am using it for broadcasting. I guess it shouldn't be too much of a problem to get queues up and running. Feel free to leave an answer for me to accept if you want.

Comment: @patricus thanks, I didn't know that about processes. I was looking into it before but I went with the queues. You should create answer for this one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a queued job. Laravel makes this very easy with [Laravel Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues).

With queues, you setup a queue driver (database, redis, Amazon SQS, etc), and then you have one to many queue workers that are continuously running. When you put a job on the queue from your `webhook` method, it will be picked up by one of your queue workers and run in a separate process. The act of dispatching a queued job to a queue is very quick, though, so your `webhook` method will return quickly while the real work is being done by the queue worker.

The linked documentation has all the details, but the general process will be:

1. Setup a queue connection. You mention you're already using redis, I would start with that.
2. Use `php artisan make:job CloneGitRepo` to create a `CloneGitRepo` job class.

   - It should implement the `Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue` interface so that Laravel knows to send this job to a queue when it is dispatched.
   - Make sure to define properties on the class for any data you pass into the constructor. This is necessary so the worker can rebuild the job correctly when it is pulled off the queue.
   - The queue worker will call the `handle()` method to process the job. Any dependencies can be type hinted here and they will be injected from the IoC container.
3. To dispatch the job to the queue, you can either use the global `dispatch()` helper function, or call the static `dispatch()` method on the job itself.

   - `dispatch(new CloneGitRepo($url));`
   - `CloneGitRepo::dispatch($url);`

So, your webhook would look like:

```
public function webhook(Request $request)
{
    // The type of GitHub event that we receive.
    $event = $request->header('X-GitHub-Event');

    $url = $this->createCloneUrl();

    CloneGitRepo::dispatch($url);

    return new Response('Webhook received succesfully', 200);
}
```

Comment: Also make sure to update your `.env` to use the right queue driver since otherwise you will be getting no output and no way to debug. Thanks for your answer!